# Issue with JUnit in eclipse

Tags: java, junit5

I have a weird problem. I have a work where I have to complete the methods and run the test cases provided by Uni. I have completed all my work but now unable to run the test class.

Following namespace was mentioned in the class

`import org. code junit.jupiter.api.*;`

I have downloaded the jar file for **JUnit 5** and imported in the build path of my project. All red errors vanished but now when I right click and do `Run as` - I don't see the option as *run Junit tests*. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say without seeing anything but (at least if you work with eclipse IDE don't know about others) make sure to put the JUnit code into JUnit Case files and not java files, if you put them in another folder make sure this folder is a source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new `JUnit Test Case`

[image]

Don't forget `@Test` anotation in something like that:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class stackoverflow {

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals(0, 1);
    }
}
```

Right Click on the new `JUnit Test Case` Java file, and choose `Run As -> New configuration`

[image]

Choose `new Configuration`

[image]

Choose JUnit5

[image]

Run your application:
[image]